# Send data from Arduino to Android not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

We are doing a project where we move a servo motor to open and close a lock with Arduino and Bluetooth HC-06. We are trying to send one number (1 or 2) as the state of the servo motor before doing anything, as soon as we connect our app to the Bluetooth HC-06 just to know if the lock is already open or close (we are using EEPROM to not lose the last position of the servo). However, with our code we receive the data but the servo stop working well. If we delete the first two lines from the loop, it will work but we will not know the initial state of the servo. How can we solve this?

```
char state;
Servo myservo;

int btx=3;
int brx=2;

SoftwareSerial blue(btx,brx);

int pos = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);    
  myservo.attach(9);
  blue.begin(9600);

  // An EEPROM value of 1 == UNLOCKED and a value of 2 == LOCKED
  if(EEPROM.read(0) == 1){ //Lock opened         
    myservo.write(70);
    delay(200);
    pos = 1;
    //blue.println(1); not working
  }
  else if(EEPROM.read(0) == 2){ //Lock closed 
    myservo.write(180);
    delay(200);
    pos = 2;
    //blue.println(2); not working
  }
  //blue.println(pos); not working
}

void loop() {
  while(!blue.available()){ // <-- The problem is in this two lines
      blue.println(pos); // send state to app
  }
  String voice;
  while(blue.available()){
    delay(10);                 
    char c = blue.read();   
    if (c == '#'){
      break;                   
    }
    voice += c;               
  }

  if(voice.length() > 0){
    if (voice == "open"){ 
      myservo.write(70);
      EEPROM.write(0, 1);
      blue.println(1);
      delay(15);
    }
    else if (voice == "close"){
      myservo.write(180); 
      EEPROM.write(0, 2);
      blue.println(2);
      delay(15);
  }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those two lines are an infinite loop! so you should change your code to this and give your code a chance to continue :)

```
void loop() {
        if(!blue.available()){
            blue.println(pos);
        }else if(blue.available()){
            String voice;

            while(blue.available()){
                delay(10);
                char c = blue.read();
                if (c == '#'){
                    break;
                }
                voice += c;

                if(voice.length() > 0){
                    if (voice == "open"){
                        myservo.write(70);
                        EEPROM.write(0, 1);
                        blue.println(1);
                        delay(15);
                    }
                    else if (voice == "close"){
                        myservo.write(180);
                        EEPROM.write(0, 2);
                        blue.println(2);
                        delay(15);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```